# Cleaning Visual Basic Code

Tags: vb.net

I have some code here that I have helped modified, however there is a portion in this code that can be simplified more (the *if*  *orelse* statements). I know it has something to do with a collections class or an array, but I'm stumped on how to change it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function GetLastName(ByVal accountName As String) As String

    Dim lastName As  
    Dim stringArray As Array = accountName.Split(" ")
    Dim lastIndex = stringArray.Length - 1  'lastIndex will serve as the UpperBound of the Array
    Dim lastElement = stringArray(lastIndex).ToUpper

    If ((lastElement.Equals("JR")) OrElse (lastElement.Equals("JR.")) _
    OrElse (lastElement.Equals("SR")) OrElse (lastElement.Equals("SR.")) _
    OrElse (lastElement.Equals("I")) OrElse (lastElement.Equals("II")) _
    OrElse (lastElement.Equals("III")) OrElse (lastElement.Equals("IV")) _
    OrElse (lastElement.Equals("M.D.")) OrElse (lastElement.Equals("M.D")) _
    OrElse (lastElement.Equals("PH.D.")) OrElse (lastElement.Equals("PHD.")) _
    OrElse (lastElement.Equals("PHARM.D")) OrElse (lastElement.Equals("M.B.A"))) Then
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim titles As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

titles.Add("JR")
titles.Add("JR.")
titles.Add("SR")
titles.Add("SR.")
' ....

Return titles.Contains(lastElement)
```